# How to find number of sub images in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a large black image which consist of 6 small objects, how do I find these 6 objects ?

I'm new to this image field, have heard that openCV could help.

Below is the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach sample input image ?

Comment: Have given the google drive link

Comment: Why was this question marked as "unclear"? It is extremely clear what OP is asking. OP states that he wants to be able to detect the 6 objects in the image, potentially using OpenCV or some other approach

Comment: Thanks bud for giving out more clarification to my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below case as a starting point:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img =  cv2.imread('example_02.png')
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# gaussian blur 
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(15,15),0)

# simple thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

mask = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype="uint8")
for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

res_final = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("detection", res_final)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

**Figure 1**: Mask created using contours detection.

[image]

**Figure 2**: Detected objects in the original image.

[image]